# How B-trees are optimized for systems that read and write large blocks of data?

Tags: database-performance, b-tree

It probably looks like a simple question to you, but please help me to clarify my understanding of the whole workflow. One of B-trees advantages is that "B-tree is optimized for systems that read and write large blocks of data" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). I wonder if the following is correct:

1. Case when B-tree's nodes contain both keys and data (as opposed to containing keys and "pointers" to data stored on disc). Then the whole B-tree should be stored on disc, since large DB implemented by this tree does not fit in memory. Then it is clear why the reading large blocks makes difference: when we are looking for a specific key, we retrieve a block with several "suspicious" keys with one disc access. OK, but what if a new key is inserted: how can we be sure it gets in the same block as the other keys of the node? Wiki suggests usage of partially full blocks to speed up insertions and deletions. Is it the only reasonable way?
2. Case when B-tree's nodes contain keys and "pointers" to data stored on disc. Then the B-tree and the data are "separated". B-tree can be stored on the disc, or in the memory. If it is stored on the disc, the situation is basically the same. If B-tree is in the memory, then I do not see any advantages in reading large blocks of data. Am I missing something very simple, or such a scheme (data on disc, index B-tree in the memory) is not used at all?

And yes, I did check SO, but still did not quite get it.

Comment: I believe technically this question is more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ which is intended for "whiteboard" type programming problems, while SO is more for problems with code and IDEs.

Comment: As to your question, which I don't have time to fully answer, B-trees are all about *finding* the data efficiently rather than loading and storing it. For large datasets, an efficient method of finding the data affects performance a lot more than the time it takes to read it off of disk.

Comment: @BergQuester "B-trees are all about finding the data efficiently" - precisely, and to find a key efficiently, B-trees use loading by blocks.

Comment: Maybe it is more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com , but there are a lot of similar B-tree questions here - see related questions on the right.